# Post on visitors website when ??? accours (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, post

I have a website running wordpress. I have facebook login plugins, but I would like to be able to automatic post on visitors wall, whenevery they get points or perhaps other scenaries as well? Is there a plugin which enables me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plugin, and autoposting is not allowed. You would need to authorize the user with the `publish_actions` permission for using the `/me/feed` endpoint to post something on his wall. And you would need to get `publish_actions` reviewed by Facebook before you can go public with it. You will never get that permission approved for autoposting. Every single post on the user wall must get approved by the user, and prefilling is not allowed - the message always must be 100% user generated.

Btw, rewarding a user for sharing something on his wall is not allowed either.

Platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: And rewarding users for sharing (by giving them “points” or anything else) is also not allowed.

Comment: yeah, i will add that too, just in case